# Threshold in OpenCV does not detect the full object that I want to get. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to detect the egg from a video feed and when I try to use threshold on it, it does not get the full egg.

I tried to apply different threshold steps from this https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html

Applying the threshold to different contours, below are the results

```
ret, img = cap.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
ret2,th4 = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
ret3,th5 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

dummy,cnts,hier = cv2.findContours(th1,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in cnts:
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    if M["m00"] != 0:
        cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    else:
        cX, cY = 0, 0
    cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.circle(img, (cX, cY), 2, (0, 0, 0), -1)
cv2.imshow("Global",th1)
cv2.imshow("Adaptive Mean",th2)
cv2.imshow("Adaptive Gaussian",th3)
cv2.imshow("Otsu's",th4)
cv2.imshow("Otsu's after Blur",th5)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZaxc.jpg

UPDATE:
After using the answer from @Martin, I've come up with this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EQVM.jpg

Through getting the contour with the largest area. But there were other contours with a big area also. The next question is what can I do to filter out the other contour below? I'm thinking of identifying which contours has corners or not because the egg is elliptical. Other way is to crop out the image since the egg is only on the upper part of the image but I don't know how.

CODE:

```
dummy,cnts,hier = cv2.findContours(close.astype(np.uint8),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#print (len(cnts))

for c in cnts:
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    print (area)
    if area >46000:
        if M["m00"] != 0:
            cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
            cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
        else:
            cX, cY = 0, 0
        cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(img, (cX, cY), 2, (0, 0, 0), -1)
cv2.imshow("th5",img)
```

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting full Egg is because the threshold is too high. You need to lower it a little bit

like:

```
limit = 100 # possible lower
ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(gray,limit,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Your problem is quite big though, because the background (object on which the egg is) has the same color as your egg. You may want to try edge detection instead of thresholding.

Check this out:

[image]

During playing with your image I was able to get the edges(only half way) :

[image]

code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('eBxV8IA.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(15,15),0)
lap = cv2.Laplacian(blur,cv2.CV_64F)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(lap,(45,45),0)
cv2.imshow("Global",blur)
```

I was able to exactly detect the egg, but unfortunately also with a lot of noice
[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('eBxV8IA.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(15,15),0)
lap = cv2.Laplacian(blur,cv2.CV_64F)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(lap,(45,45),0)
blur[blur<0]=0
blur = 255.*blur/np.amax(blur)


dummy,cnts,hier = cv2.findContours(blur.astype(np.uint8),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in cnts:
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    if M["m00"] != 0:
        cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    else:
        cX, cY = 0, 0
    cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.circle(img, (cX, cY), 2, (0, 0, 0), -1)
cv2.imshow("Global",img)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to do that also and was searching if I could get the contour which consists of the egg. Do you have any suggestions for that? Also, If I change the color of the background to a lighter color, would it be easier?

Comment: 1) it would b easier if the color is different( you can use HSV filtering) or if the egg and  background has oppositie intesity - egg white, background gray or opposite.  2) I dont have much suggestion to extract exactly that contour, only Idea I have is that egg has round shape so I would somehow use it. I would try for example to go through all contour points and see if there is any radial change in direction (egg is round so there is no radical change, but square for example has radical change of direction at the corners). You can also dismiss contours with small or too big areas,

Comment: blur[blur<0]=0
    blur = 255.*blur/np.amax(blur)

what is this code for may I ask?

Comment: any value in blur below 0 will be assigned 0. The second one is harder one. Somehow the blur is not cosidered standard 8bit image... so I had to transform it to 8bit (black 0 , white 255)